# XML serialization error in C# / WCF with inherited classes

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I have a given WSDL schema by a webservice and I have to build a WCF transmitter to use the service. Generating and building works fine. Unfortunately I get an error when starting the transmission:

> The top XML element 'RequestContext' from namespace 'http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac' references distinct types RequestContextBaseType and RequestContextType. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types.

Let's have a look at the sample interface to show the problem:

WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions
    xmlns:oas="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacs"
    xmlns:oast="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        name="OrgaAuthService"
        targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacs">

    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema>
            <xs:import namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst"
                       schemaLocation="OrgaAuthServiceTypes.xsd"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <!-- Registration -->
    <wsdl:message name="RegisterOrganizationRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="oast:RegisterOrganization"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="RegisterOrganizationResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="oast:RegisterOrganizationResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <!-- GetStatusFromRegistration -->
    <wsdl:message name="GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistrationRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="oast:GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistration"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistrationResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="oast:GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistrationResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="OrganizationAuthenticationPort">
        <wsdl:operation name="RegisterOrganization">
            <wsdl:input message="oas:RegisterOrganizationRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="oas:RegisterOrganizationResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetStatusFromRegisterOrganization">
            <wsdl:input message="oas:GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistrationRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="oas:GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistrationResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>   
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="OrganizationAuthenticationSOAPBinding" type="oas:OrganizationAuthenticationPort">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>

        <wsdl:operation name="RegisterOrganization">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="OrganizationAuthenticationFault">
                <soap:fault name="OrganizationAuthenticationFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="GetStatusFromRegisterOrganization">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="OrganizationAuthenticationFault">
                <soap:fault name="OrganizationAuthenticationFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="OrganizationAuthenticationService">
        <wsdl:port name="OrganizationAuthentication" binding="oas:OrganizationAuthenticationSOAPBinding">
            <soap:address
                    location="http://tst.mycompany.com/services/OrganizationAuthentication"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

OrgaAuthServiceTypes.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst"
    xmlns:iast="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst" xmlns:oac="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="0.0">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac"
        schemaLocation="OrgaAuth.xsd"/>

    <!-- definitions RegisterOrganization -->
    <xs:element name="RegisterOrganization" type="oac:RegisterOrganizationRequestType"/>
    <xs:element name="RegisterOrganizationResponse" type="oac:RegisterOrganizationResponseType"/>

    <!-- definitions GetStatusFromRegisterOrganization -->
    <xs:element name="GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistration"
        type="oac:GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistrationRequestType"/>
    <xs:element name="GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistrationResponse"
        type="oac:GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistrationResponseType"/>


</xs:schema>
```

OrgaAuth.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac"
    xmlns:oac="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="0.0">

    <xs:complexType name="RegisterOrganizationRequestType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="RequestContext" type="oac:RequestContextBaseType"/>
            <xs:element name="OrganizationRegistration" type="oac:OrganizationRegistrationType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="RegisterOrganizationResponseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ResponseContext" type="oac:ResponseContextType"/>
            <xs:element name="JobKey" type="oac:JobKeyType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistrationRequestType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="RequestContext" type="oac:RequestContextType"/>      
            <xs:element name="JobKey" type="oac:JobKeyType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistrationResponseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ResponseContext" type="oac:ResponseContextType"/>            
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="Success" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Error" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="JobFinished" type="xs:boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- shared types -->
    <xs:complexType name="RequestContextBaseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CompanyName" type="xs:string"> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="RequestContextType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="oac:RequestContextBaseType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="RequestID" type="xs:string"> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ResponseContextType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="RequestID" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="OrganizationRegistrationType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- simple types -->
    <xs:simpleType name="JobKeyType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="IDType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="255"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

This results in the following Reference.cs class when generating with SvcUtil.exe :

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Dieser Code wurde von einem Tool generiert.
//     Laufzeitversion:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Änderungen an dieser Datei können falsches Verhalten verursachen und gehen verloren, wenn
//     der Code erneut generiert wird.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------



[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacs", ConfigurationName="OrganizationAuthenticationPort")]
public interface OrganizationAuthenticationPort
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    RegisterOrganizationResponse RegisterOrganization(RegisterOrganizationRequest request);

    // CODEGEN: Der Nachrichtenvertrag wird generiert, da der Vorgang mehrere Rückgabewerte aufweist.
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="*")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RegisterOrganizationResponse> RegisterOrganizationAsync(RegisterOrganizationRequest request);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationResponse GetStatusFromRegisterOrganization(GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationRequest request);

    // CODEGEN: Der Nachrichtenvertrag wird generiert, da der Vorgang mehrere Rückgabewerte aufweist.
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="*")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationResponse> GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationAsync(GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationRequest request);
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(RequestContextType))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.7.2558.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
public partial class RequestContextBaseType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string companyNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string CompanyName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.companyNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.companyNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CompanyName");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.7.2558.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
public partial class ResponseContextType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string requestIDField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string RequestID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.requestIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.requestIDField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("RequestID");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.7.2558.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
public partial class OrganizationRegistrationType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.7.2558.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
public partial class RequestContextType : RequestContextBaseType
{

    private string requestIDField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string RequestID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.requestIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.requestIDField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("RequestID");
        }
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="RegisterOrganization", WrapperNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class RegisterOrganizationRequest
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
    public RequestContextBaseType RequestContext;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac", Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
    public OrganizationRegistrationType OrganizationRegistration;

    public RegisterOrganizationRequest()
    {
    }

    public RegisterOrganizationRequest(RequestContextBaseType RequestContext, OrganizationRegistrationType OrganizationRegistration)
    {
        this.RequestContext = RequestContext;
        this.OrganizationRegistration = OrganizationRegistration;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="RegisterOrganizationResponse", WrapperNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class RegisterOrganizationResponse
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
    public ResponseContextType ResponseContext;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac", Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
    public string JobKey;

    public RegisterOrganizationResponse()
    {
    }

    public RegisterOrganizationResponse(ResponseContextType ResponseContext, string JobKey)
    {
        this.ResponseContext = ResponseContext;
        this.JobKey = JobKey;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.7.2558.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac", IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemChoiceType
{

    /// <remarks/>
    Error,

    /// <remarks/>
    Success,
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistration", WrapperNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationRequest
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
    public RequestContextType RequestContext;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac", Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
    public string JobKey;

    public GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationRequest()
    {
    }

    public GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationRequest(RequestContextType RequestContext, string JobKey)
    {
        this.RequestContext = RequestContext;
        this.JobKey = JobKey;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistrationResponse", WrapperNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationResponse
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
    public ResponseContextType ResponseContext;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac", Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Error", typeof(string), Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Success", typeof(string), Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public string Item;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac", Order=2)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType ItemElementName;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac", Order=3)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac")]
    public bool JobFinished;

    public GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationResponse()
    {
    }

    public GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationResponse(ResponseContextType ResponseContext, string Item, ItemChoiceType ItemElementName, bool JobFinished)
    {
        this.ResponseContext = ResponseContext;
        this.Item = Item;
        this.ItemElementName = ItemElementName;
        this.JobFinished = JobFinished;
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface OrganizationAuthenticationPortChannel : OrganizationAuthenticationPort, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class OrganizationAuthenticationPortClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<OrganizationAuthenticationPort>, OrganizationAuthenticationPort
{

    public OrganizationAuthenticationPortClient()
    {
    }

    public OrganizationAuthenticationPortClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    public OrganizationAuthenticationPortClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public OrganizationAuthenticationPortClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public OrganizationAuthenticationPortClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    RegisterOrganizationResponse OrganizationAuthenticationPort.RegisterOrganization(RegisterOrganizationRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.RegisterOrganization(request);
    }

    public ResponseContextType RegisterOrganization(RequestContextBaseType RequestContext, OrganizationRegistrationType OrganizationRegistration, out string JobKey)
    {
        RegisterOrganizationRequest inValue = new RegisterOrganizationRequest();
        inValue.RequestContext = RequestContext;
        inValue.OrganizationRegistration = OrganizationRegistration;
        RegisterOrganizationResponse retVal = ((OrganizationAuthenticationPort)(this)).RegisterOrganization(inValue);
        JobKey = retVal.JobKey;
        return retVal.ResponseContext;
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RegisterOrganizationResponse> RegisterOrganizationAsync(RegisterOrganizationRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.RegisterOrganizationAsync(request);
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationResponse OrganizationAuthenticationPort.GetStatusFromRegisterOrganization(GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetStatusFromRegisterOrganization(request);
    }

    public ResponseContextType GetStatusFromRegisterOrganization(RequestContextType RequestContext, string JobKey, out string Item, out ItemChoiceType ItemElementName, out bool JobFinished)
    {
        GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationRequest inValue = new GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationRequest();
        inValue.RequestContext = RequestContext;
        inValue.JobKey = JobKey;
        GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationResponse retVal = ((OrganizationAuthenticationPort)(this)).GetStatusFromRegisterOrganization(inValue);
        Item = retVal.Item;
        ItemElementName = retVal.ItemElementName;
        JobFinished = retVal.JobFinished;
        return retVal.ResponseContext;
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationResponse> GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationAsync(GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationAsync(request);
    }
}
```

As you can see the schema itself is legal. The problem is the derived class **RequestContextType** from **RequestContextBaseType**.
This error seems to occur independently of where in the XML structure a tag RequestContext is situated - or something else using **RequestContextType** or **RequestContextBaseType**. It seems to be about the namespace, and that the base class is in the same namespace as the derived class.

Apparently there must be an XML attribute to solve the problem? But which one? I only saw something for arrays (XmlArrayItem https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.120).aspx , probably? ), but no explanation how to do with "normal" classes.

Any idea?

Obviously it is out of question to change the namespace, nor to change the name, as this whould result in an invalid XML SOAP-request for the webservice...

---

Examples as the XMLs would look like:

RegisterOrganization:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iast:RegisterOrganization xmlns:oac="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac"
 xmlns:iast="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst file:/D:/projects/swissdec/samples/sUA_WCFinterfaceBug_BspExternNeutral/Transmitter/Wcf.Transmitter/Proxy/oa/OrgaAuthServiceTypes.xsd">
    <oac:RequestContext>
        <oac:CompanyName>CompanyName0</oac:CompanyName>
    </oac:RequestContext>
    <oac:OrganizationRegistration>
        <oac:Name>Name0</oac:Name>
    </oac:OrganizationRegistration>
</iast:RegisterOrganization>
```

GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iast:GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistration xmlns:oac="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oac"
 xmlns:iast="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst file:/D:/projects/swissdec/samples/sUA_WCFinterfaceBug_BspExternNeutral/Transmitter/Wcf.Transmitter/Proxy/oa/OrgaAuthServiceTypes.xsd">
    <oac:RequestContext>
        <oac:CompanyName>CompanyName0</oac:CompanyName>
        <oac:RequestID>RequestID0</oac:RequestID>
    </oac:RequestContext>
    <oac:JobKey>JobKey1111</oac:JobKey>
</iast:GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistration>
```

Comment: What is the root tag of the xml?  I think it is RegisterOrganizationRequestType and you do not have a class for the root.

Comment: I seems RegisterOrganizationRequest is the root for the RegisterOrganization operation generated by SvcUtil.exe. So far I did not really have problems in other projects with the Reference.cs by it.

Comment: Did you try changing wrapper on following : [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="GetStatusFromOrganizationRegistration", WrapperNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/schema/oacst", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class GetStatusFromRegisterOrganizationRequest

Comment: Change something there does not make any difference to the problem. The error message remains as before.  :-(